# Enabling local network users to access my WAMP sites

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I am trying to access my local webpage (currently, an only basic HTML page) from another computer inside the local network.

I can access my mage from localhost/Testpage and from the IP address (10.XXX.XXX.XXX/Testpage) but can't access it from another computer.

**Website (10.XXX.XXX.XXX) is Online but isn’t Responding to Connection Attempts**

Any idea?

I have changed the following:

httpd-vhosts.config

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The Wamp-server is online and all services are running.

I have seen the following solutions.

*Cannot access wamp server on local network

why wamp server put online/ offline option is missing?

How to enable local network users to access my WAMP sites?

How to enable local network users to access my WAMP sites?*

Comment: So how are you trying to address this site from the other PC's?

Comment: Do remember that is you are using `localhost` on another PC that will definitely only attempt to find a web server on the Other PC and never ever leave that PC looking for a site.

Comment: typing IP address http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX/

Comment: Could this be a FireWall blocking your access

Comment: Might I also take this opertunity to point you towards [this article on the WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)

Comment: @ RiggsFolly yes, it is the Firewall blocking my access, but how can I overcome it without deactivating firewall (in companies, it is not desirable to play with firewall). any idea?

Comment: If you cannot amend the firewall yourself, you will have to ask the Admins to make the changes

Comment: Normally a firewall will allow you to set exceptions, which will allow for example TCP connections through port 80